# Regex Matching line by line and stop when a specific string appears

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using `re`with python and I can't get my logic work around this problem. 
My text is the following:

```
(...)
 Zelite and FOS ont are limiting small bowel disturbance. 
Indications :
chronical kidney disease (IRC)
management of urolithiasis and low tract urinary syndrome
hepatic encephalitis
management of acidophils urinary stone : purine, cystine…
Contraindication :
pregnancy, lactation, growth
Length of the treatment : ... 
(...)
```

I just want to get things between Indications and Contraindication. Each row would be another group.

So far I'm nearly satisfied but that's not exactly it :

`([I,i]ndication[s]*\s*\:{0,1})(\s*.*\n)*? Contraindication`

which gives me :

```
Indications :
    chronical kidney disease (IRC)
    management of urolithiasis and low tract urinary syndrome
    hepatic encephalitis
    management of acidophils urinary stone : purine, cystine…
 Contraindication
```

I would like to get rid of "Contraindication" but negative lookahead doesn't seem to work with `:?`. I don't know why. A .replace("Contraindication","") is always possible but I'm looking for proper Regex solution.
I don't know if that possible with regex but it's that possible to have a group for each line (between indications and contraindications) without knowing in advance how many lines there will be ?

[You can check what I did here on the Regex simulator](http://regexr.com/3rtip)

Have a great day

Comment: Are you using PyPi regex module (I ask because you say *Each row would be another group* and Python `re` does not keep a capture stack)? BTW, you need a positive lookahead, `([Ii]ndications*\s*:?)(\s*.*\n)*?(?=Contraindication)`. Maybe a [`(?s)[Ii]ndications*\s*:?(.*?)Contraindication`](https://regex101.com/r/CAtHTE/3) is  enough and grab Group 1 value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookahead will match a string that **isn't** followed by whatever is in the lookahead. A positive lookahead is what you want. This will match a string that **is** followed by whatever is in the lookahead, without including the lookahead in your match. In this case, you can do this:

`(?s)(?<=[iI]ndications :).*(?=Contraindication)`

[As you can see here, it captures exactly what you want.](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/25)

To break this down for you, `(?s)` enables the single line flag, `(?<=[iI]ndications :)` matches a string that is preceded by `indications :` or `Indications :`

`.*` captures everything in between

and `(?=Contraindication)` means the string must be followed by `Contraindication`

Neither the lookahead or the lookbehind are included in the match. If you want to also include the word indications, just remove the `(?<=)` surrounding it.

Comment: That's a great and pedagogic answer. Thank you very much.